# 301 Redirect with cet= parameter

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to make a 301 redirect of a url in `http://website.com/example-old/?cet=3132` format to a page `https://www.website.com/example-new/`.

I have tried several times via .htaccess with the classic method:

`redirect 301 /example-old/?cet=3132 https://www.website.com/example-new/`

The redirect works, but I don't get what I want. In fact the final url becomes `https://www.website.com/example-new/?cet=3132`.

In short, the `?cet=3132` doesn't disappear and this is not good for me.

I found this invaluable resource which recommends a mod_rewrite method: [301 redirect for old urls with language parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192502/301-redirect-for-old-urls-with-language-parameter)

Sure I'll try it, but I was wondering: will it work even with the cet=3132 parameter?

Thanks to those who can answer, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use the rewriting module for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cet=3132$
RewriteRule ^/?example-old/?$ https://www.example.com/example-new/ [QSD,L,R=301]
```

The `QSD` flag will take care to *remove* the query string during the redirection.

It is a good idea to start out with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as intended. That prevents nasty caching issues.

Comment: It doesn't work..

Comment: @SEOriented "It doesn't work.. " has never helped anyone anywhere at any time. Please be specific, what does that actually mean? Do you get an error? Which? Do you get a response, but not the expected one? What response? Do you see any error in your http server's error log file? Which error? What test request did you make? In what situation?

Comment: you're right but if I could explain precisely what's going on I could probably fix it myself. At the moment, if I search http://website.com/example-old/?cet=3132 I get a 404 error. Even though the page https://www.website.com/example-new/ exists. I hope I was more helpful

Comment: @SEOriented Does the URL visible in the browser`s address bar change or not?

Comment: @SEOriented Are you really sure that you don't have any other rewriting rules implemented?

Comment: @SEOriented And did you really make sure that you are not looking at cached results in your browser? Remember: always test with a fresh anonymous browser window. Also you should open your browser's console and monitor the actual traffic between your browser and the http server. What do you see when you make a test request?

Comment: The URL visible in the browser's address does not change. I don't know if I have any other rewriting rules that make a conflict.

Comment: My website run on WordPress, i don't know if there are any other rewriting rules into the htaccess.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress